# Can users be banned from suggesting edits?

Tags: support, editing, suggested-edits

A user can be banned from asking a [question](https://askubuntu.com/help/question-bans) and from [answering](https://askubuntu.com/help/answer-bans). A user can also be banned from reviewing. So is there any rule for editing posts?

Once they have at least 2k reputation a user can edit any post. Can a user who has less than 2k reputation be banned from suggesting edits if s/he has many edit suggestions rejected?

Comment: Can you perhaps give context for why you're asking this?

Comment: There is no specific reason for it. When I was rejecting suggested edit three times of same user, i just got curious to know about if there is any automatic banning system for it

Comment: If you think the user is honestly trying to help, but is making bad edits, maybe you can "reject and edit" once or twice with semi-long edit comment that the user can see. Then switch to "accept and edit" to see if s/he improves in editing from the lessons you provide with your edits. Of course, if the edits seem to not be in good faith, the point could be moot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Yes, they can, per the Meta.SE thread which requested this feature and has since been marked as 'completed' meaning the feature is available.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221832/moderators-should-be-able-to-manually-ban-users-from-suggesting-edits)  There's an automated system in place, I believe, though the specifics of that system are not public, so if they get enough edit rejects in a row it'll squish people.

That said, if there's a specific case where this may be necessary, consider reaching out to moderators (perhaps in chat, or through flags on a post using "Custom" reasons, and explain which user and which edit you're concerned about, but only once or twice, not many times) about the user, to ask us to look at their review actions and consider whether they're being overly disruptive or not.

Comment: The MSE question (vaguely) suggests there is an automatic ban mechanism. Could you clarify how that is triggered maybe? The answer showing how mods can edit-ban (seekrit knowledge!) is clear but that point is obscure I think.

Comment: @Zanna Outside of the MSE answer, it gives no details about the automatic banning systems, simliarly to the answer/question ban mechanisms.  This suggests they aren't publicizing the 'specifics', so that would need its own Meta.SE inquiry, I believe.

Comment: Fair enough! Thank you :)